# Web API model binding woe

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fetch, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm struggling to post some data to a web page...

```
[HttpPost("{id:int}/stuff")]
public IActionResult Add([FromBody] viewModel viewModel, [FromRoute] int id)
```

Fetch call...

```
    fetch("api/" + id + "/stuff", {

                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                credentials: "same-origin",
                method: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ text: text })

            })
```

View model

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "t")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

`Id` is correct but `viewModel` is *null*.

What's the next step?

Comment: `PropertyName = "t"` but you're sending `{ text: text }`?

Comment: @abbot web api binding doesn’t know about newtonsoft json.

Comment: @nkosi I have updated the name of the parameter in the text.

Comment: Have you actually tried sending `{ t: text }`?

Comment: Yes it knows about newtonsoft json it is the primary JSON parser used by the framework

Comment: `The JsonInputFormatter is the default formatter and is based on Json.NET.` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1#bind-formatted-data-from-the-request-body

Comment: Yes, I tried sending “t”. It didn’t work. Tomorrow morning I’ll try it again. But I suspect I’ll end up using request.form. I hate this crap.

Comment: if you are passing a complextype - you can ommit the [fromBody]

Comment: Good to know. I’ll try that too. But I think it’s obscene how difficult this is. Over two decades ago, this was trivial.

Comment: @Haris that only works if using the new `[ApiController]` attribute in .NET Core 2.1.  `[FromBody]` is required for an API action method when the body is `application/json`.

Comment: ah apologises, i did not see the .net-core tag, oops

Comment: Well it works now with "t", plus the JSON should have been assigned to "body" and not "data". So, was nearly there. Sorry for my bad attitude last night - was driving me out of my mind.